# Force Apache to create files so they are owned by app user instead of Apache

Tags: linux, apache, redhat

I have multiple PHP applications hosted in Apache on Redhat 8.

Some of the libraries used in these web apps generate files owned by Apache.

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 apache    apache      35 Dec 16 12:54 cf8d2#setClass.cache.php
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 apache    apache      35 Dec 16 12:54 c8dds#setSchemeId.cache.php
```

I have a deployment process which deletes a release before deploying the new release. Since these files are owned by Apache, the deployment fails as the webadmin user cannot remove these files.

The app files themselves are owned by a user/group called webadmin.

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 webadmin webadmin 2848 Dec 16 12:59 index.php
```

Is the a way to force Apache to create files owned by webadmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the webadmin user to the group of apache. Then you should have enough permissions. Otherwise you could use ACLs and give the user permissions for that directory.

[ACLs on Redhat 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/assembly_managing-access-control-list_configuring-basic-system-settings)

Here is a manual how to use the ACLs. I think that is the easiest way. Otherwise you have to run the deployment with higher privileges.

Or you give the user sudo rights to the folder like this.

[Sudo rights in a particular directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/206827/sudoers-config-to-allow-edit-of-files-in-particular-directory-and-children)

So there are some ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks René Höhle. The reason I asked is during a migration from one data center to another, I noticed Apache was writing files that had the correct owner set e.g. mysiteadmin, instead of the Apache user on the original DC. I've been attempting to mimic this in the new DC without ACL or sudoing. There must be a module or something I've missed that forces Apache to write files and set the website owner as owner.